# Twig : Included template extends parent Javascript bloc?

Tags: javascript, symfony, inheritance, twig, include

I am coding a project on Symfony, and for a page I need to split into several templates that I include in the main template.

Imagine this configuration:

**base.html.twig**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        {% block stylesheets %}{% endblock %}

    </head>

    <body>
        {% block body %}{% endblock %}

        {{ encore_entry_script_tags('js/app') }} //like Jquery

        {% block javascripts %}{% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

**template1.html.twig**

```
{% extends "base.html.twig" %}

#template1.html.twig
{% block body %}
    Some content

    {% include "template2.html.twig" %}
{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}

    {# Some scripts . . . #}
{% endblock %}
```

**template2.html.twig :**

```
#template2.html.twig
{% block body %}
    Some content
{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}

    {# Some scripts using Jquery . . . #}
{% endblock %}
```

In this configuration, I cannot use Jquery in the **template2.html.twig**, even if I imported it as a CDN in the **base.html.twig** template.

So how do you get template 2 to inherit the script imports made in **base.html.twig** ?

This is only a simple example here.

The real problem I face is similar.
I have in my **base.html.twig** all my compulsory imports which are transmitted to the child templates, and it works.

On the other hand, if my templates which extend the **base.html.twig** also include other templates, then I can no longer use the scripts imported into my **base.html.twig**

Comment: I assume you forgot `{% extends "base.html.twig" %}` in the `template2.html.twig` example, right?

Comment: In general, if a `block` is present in an overlaying template (in this case `base`) and gets overwritten in a child template (like `template1`), you can include the parent block part via the `parent` keyword. See [`extends` twig doc](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tags/extends.html)

Comment: If template2 extends template1 than you overwrite the javascripts block of template1. But like goulashsoup said you can use {{ parent() }} inside the block to include the content of the parent block. Else if template2 extends the base template then of course the whole template1 is out of scope,

Comment: You should place any common used (javascript) libraries *outside* the `javascripts` block, this way you don't need to call `{{ parent() }}` each time

Comment: The problem here is that if in the template2.html.twig, I extend the base.html.twig, I will have a bug in the block body which will position it badly. But I will have my JS.

And if I choose not to do extensions, then my body will be well positioned, but I will not be able to use my jquery

Comment: What do you mean with `positioned`? You mean in the source output?